# How to draw the gray 8 bits image acquired form camera device using direct2d

Tags: direct2d

I can not find the correct DXGI_FORMAT_* to represent a gray 8 bits image. Can anybody suggest a proper way drawing gray image using direct2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXGI_FORMAT_A8_UNorm or DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM